# Progress bar using waveformers. Js like audio tag have

Tags: javascript, audio

I am new to development can anyone help me to to do the progress bar using waveformer.js like audio tag have.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this example](https://codepen.io/sunify/pen/eifgz) from codepen is very nice!

**An output:**

[image: Wave]

**HTML code:**

```
<canvas id="cnv" width="140" height="140"></canvas>
```

**CSS code:**

```
body {
  background-color: #26292C;
}

#cnv {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Java Script code:**

```
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                                   || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());

(function($, _) {
  var waveLoader,
      drawWave;

  $.fn.waveLoader = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        if(typeof args[0] === 'string') {
            $(this).each(function() {
                var ldr = $(this).data('waveLoader');
                ldr[args[0]].call(ldr, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, [1]));
            });
        } else {
            var options = _.extend({
                amp: 6,
                len: 10,
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
            }, args[1] || {});
            $(this).each(function() {
                var $el = $(this);
                $el.data('waveLoader', waveLoader($el, args[0], options.color, options.amp, options.len));
            });
        }
    };

  drawWave = function(t) {
    var ctx = this.ctx;

    if(this.loop > 2) this.loop = 0;

    if(this.progress < 100) { 
      window.requestAnimationFrame(drawWave.bind(this));
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    if(this.progress >= 100) {
      return;
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.moveTo(0, this.height/2);
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.width; i += 1) {
      ctx.lineTo(
        i,
        Math.sin(i/(this.len / 2) * Math.PI - this.loop * Math.PI) * (this.amp / 2) + (this.height - this.progress * (this.height/100))
      );
    }
    ctx.lineTo(this.width, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.fill();
    this.loop += 0.08;
  };

  waveLoader = function($cnv, img, color, amp, len) {
    var that;

    that = {
      $cnv: $cnv,
      img: img,
      ctx: null,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      loop: 0,
      amp: amp,
      len: len,
      color: color,
      progress: 0,
      init: function() {
        console.log($cnv);
        this.ctx = this.$cnv[0].getContext('2d');
        this.width = this.$cnv.width();
        this.height = this.$cnv.height();
        drawWave.call(this);
      },
      setProgress: function(newProgr) {
        this.progress = Math.min(Math.max(0, newProgr), 100);
      }
    };

    that.init();

    return that;
  };
})(jQuery, _);

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_582,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
  $('#cnv').waveLoader(img, {
    amp: 8,
    len: 70
  });

  var progress = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#cnv').waveLoader('setProgress', progress);
    progress += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  }, 500);
};
```

It is worth trying it, no harm!

Comment: Thank you for help but I require same like progress bar like audio tag have